# Remove or change the Header from Google Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I know how to query Google Sheet, I want to remove or change the header name.

Cell explanation:

**G1:** data for query in `WHERE` clause

**H1:** `=QUERY(J1:J, "SELECT max(J) WHERE todate(J) = date '"&TEXT(G1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)`

**I1:** `=QUERY(J1:J, "SELECT J WHERE todate(J) = date '"&TEXT(G1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)`

**J1:** select data source

According to the query syntax

```
QUERY(data, query, [headers])
```

headers `0` will remove the header but it doesn't work to a column with a function like `max(H)`, is it possible to remove or change the header?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`label` is what you seek:

### remove header:

```
=QUERY(J1:J, 
 "select max(J) 
  where todate(J) = date '"&TEXT(G1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  label max(J)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

or you can do it like:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(J1:J, 
 "select max(J) 
  where todate(J) = date '"&TEXT(G1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

### change header:

```
=QUERY(J1:J, 
 "select max(J) 
  where todate(J) = date '"&TEXT(G1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  label max(J)'change this'", 0)
```

[image: 0]